# Why does my css displays different in chrome than in edge/firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

the problem is minimal yet very disturbing and I would like to understand what's going on. I can understand different behaviours in different browsers, yet this only happens in a little section of a big page and only on mobile-tablet versions, the bullets of an unlisted list display below their usual position.

Even more disturbing: this only happens in the mobile view on pc browser (window width < 760px), when using chrome on my phone the balls and the checks are perfectly aligned...

So far I tried the following "only chrome hack" and though it solves the issue in chrome, it screws it in firefox and edge...

Any idea why this happens?

You can see the full page here https://camishkadevelopment.netlify.app/#myprograms

```css
/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    selector{ property:value; } 
}
```

[image: edge view][image: chrome view]

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?